# Search keywords in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcuMT.png)

and I have a list of keywords

```
branches_of_sci = ['bio', 'chem', 'physics']
```

So What I want to do is create a new column and add new keywords with a separation of coma or anything else

I was able to do this temporary

```
for tok in branches_of_sci:
    df[branch] = df.astype(str).sum(axis=1).str.contains(branch)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfjrL.png)

but it generates new column for every keyword, Can I just create a new single column where all keywords found are stored.

The marked duplicate answer only finds a single keyword but what if multiple keywords match then it fails.

```
df['Col 3'] = df['Col 2'].str.extract("(" + "|".join(List1) +")", expand=False)
```

Comment: Can you explain more what failed? Can you add  [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Also I think this should help -  [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: I get it, changed dupe link. Need `findall`